# how can you tell whether convert()/convert_alpha() has already been run on a pygame.Surface?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

The title says it all, really.   I am writing functions that deal with `pygame.Surface` objects from multiple sources. Among other operations, these functions will ensure that the `Surface` objects they return have been `convert()`ed at least once (or, according to user preference, `convert_alpha()`ed), as is required to optimize them for blitting in the current display mode. But I don't want to run the the `convert()` or `convert_alpha()` methods needlessly since they create copies of the surface and therefore take up time and memory.  How do I tell whether I need to do it? I have looked at the output of `S.get_flags()` before and after `S = S.convert_alpha()` but it doesn't seem to change.  The scalar value of `S.get_alpha()` does change (from 255 to 0) but I'm not convinced that's meaningful or reliable (and it doesn't solve the problem of knowing whether you have to `.convert()` in the case where alpha blending is *not* desired).

Comment: maybe create own class with surface and extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe the existing API provides a way to do this.  I think the intended use is to convert *all* your surfaces (why wouldn't you?) so you never have to worry about it.

Perhaps it is possible to subclass `pygame.Surface` and override the convert methods to set a flag in the way you wish.